# Swift 4 -- Challenge trying to use Generics to reduce formulaic code

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I started this morning with the simple task of testing some math functions on SCNVector3s and ended up bogged down in the weeds of protocols and generics. I have been trying to implement a conceptually simple extension that allows for the production of random SCNVector3s which is especially useful for generative testing.

The following swift script does indeed allow one to easily generate random vectors. The challenge is to reduce the code replication inherent in implementing the various combinations of open and closed ranges for three dimensions (8 functions). Try as I might, I cannot figure out how to use a generic functions and/or protocols to collapse this functionality into a single method which to my C++ mind seems like a trivial task. Alas, I have learned that one can not simply think of generics and protocols as equivalent to templates.

The text of all the functions is exactly equivalent save for the argument type -- which makes it too painful for me to replicate the code. I just can't bring myself to do it even though that would have ended my tragic saga hours ago.

Any help on a solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import SceneKit

extension SCNVector3 {
    public static func random(_ range: ClosedRange<CGFloat>) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(CGFloat.random(in: range),
                          CGFloat.random(in: range),
                          CGFloat.random(in: range))
    }

    public static func random(_ range: Range<CGFloat>) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(CGFloat.random(in: range),
                          CGFloat.random(in: range),
                          CGFloat.random(in: range))
    }

    public static func random(_ xrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat>,
                              _ yrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat>,
                              _ zrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat>) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(CGFloat.random(in: xrange),
                          CGFloat.random(in: yrange),
                          CGFloat.random(in: zrange))
    }
}

for _ in 0...5 {
    print(SCNVector3.random(0...1))
}

for _ in 0...5 {
    print(SCNVector3.random(0..<1))
}

for _ in 0...5 {
    print(SCNVector3.random(0...1, 0...10, 0...100))
}

SCNVector3(x: 0.30337554055051663, y: 0.3815295391899972, z: 0.4500107875772762)
SCNVector3(x: 0.8292976915969825, y: 0.09817659394351774, z: 0.9805310965643402)
SCNVector3(x: 0.10140452934182276, y: 0.13700006723273783, z: 0.003407601812085548)
SCNVector3(x: 0.2794740490735984, y: 0.8092883659638909, z: 0.7611573009648945)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5245643085628658, y: 0.08307239252197174, z: 0.4335406226121913)
SCNVector3(x: 0.43781151814220054, y: 0.061963776367431, z: 0.18073354555266563)
SCNVector3(x: 0.10427323503781749, y: 0.8816323284041111, z: 0.7307715923086391)
SCNVector3(x: 0.36332454445518303, y: 0.7568856199566694, z: 0.43190825321532156)
SCNVector3(x: 0.8236386316508026, y: 0.8079968534291148, z: 0.3294130964530748)
SCNVector3(x: 0.038760425835524304, y: 0.8453005937068554, z: 0.11379975436886769)
SCNVector3(x: 0.9980685456027362, y: 0.6776965236898836, z: 0.6814096250296368)
SCNVector3(x: 0.01414002018834537, y: 0.1922579292321731, z: 0.5310331022793705)
SCNVector3(x: 0.6720908484435982, y: 6.815521332533848, z: 47.73040146101302)
SCNVector3(x: 0.05912412792498123, y: 7.709586490036736, z: 87.70901825047801)
SCNVector3(x: 0.9603565579370552, y: 9.627783890657632, z: 83.3390228893866)
SCNVector3(x: 0.4312469801270884, y: 1.0603895571013555, z: 73.97981933311189)
SCNVector3(x: 0.8079217337794122, y: 7.901726750285889, z: 83.322147654367)
SCNVector3(x: 0.7795445386815117, y: 6.845539611004492, z: 92.24684042413436)
```

Comment: ClosedRange and Range is not has same point. so I think you can't use generic here. but you can shorted your code by remove the second random function and change the third random function to `random(_ xrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat>,
                              _ yrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat> = xrange,
                              _ zrange: ClosedRange<CGFloat> = xrange)`

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen: I get `error: use of unresolved identifier` when I try to add a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a protocol, let's call it `Randomizable`, that joins `Range` and `ClosedRange` under the same umbrella, this will eliminate the duplication (yay :) )

```
public protocol Randomizable {
    associatedtype Value

    func random() -> Value
}

extension Range: Randomizable where Bound == CGFloat {
    public typealias Value = CGFloat

    public func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.random(in: self)
    }
}

extension ClosedRange: Randomizable where Bound == CGFloat {
    public typealias Value = CGFloat

    public func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.random(in: self)
    }
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    public static func random<R: Randomizable>(_ source: R) -> SCNVector3 where R.Value == CGFloat {
        return SCNVector3(source.random(),
                          source.random(),
                          source.random())
    }

    public static func random<R1: Randomizable, R2: Randomizable, R3: Randomizable>(
        _ xsource: R1,
        _ ysource: R2,
        _ zsource: R3) -> SCNVector3 where R1.Value == CGFloat, R2.Value == CGFloat, R3.Value == CGFloat {
        return SCNVector3(xsource.random(),
                          ysource.random(),
                          zsource.random())
    }
}
```

As a note, because `Randomizable` has associated types, the domain where that protocol can be used is limited, you can circumvent that by removing the `Value` associated type and hardcoding it to `CGFloat`. Though that would make the protocol less flexible.

Comment: I travelled this road before, but struggled getting the extension to be generic to all number that have a random function: i.e. `Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint && Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger` and `Bound:FixedWidthInteger`. Any insight on how that might be accomplished.

Comment: @RandomBits is your comment related to the edit you suggested? BTW, I didn't accept that as I think it would be better for you to add a dedicated post with that - either a new response, or a new question if that code doesn't bring the desired results

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect a more generic extension, but that won't appear to everyone else until it is peer reviewed. Here is the extension: `extension ClosedRange : Randomizable where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint,
                                           Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger {
    public typealias Value = Bound
    public func random() -> Value {
        return Value.random(in: self)
    }
}`

Comment: I will ask a new question about how to marry the two different types of numbers that have `random(in:)` functions.