# Swift 4 -- Use floating point types with `random(:in)` and integer types with `random(:in)` in single generic function

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, protocols

I have extensions to `Range` and `ClosedRange` (see below) that allow them to be used to generate random floating point values. I would like them to also be able to generate random integer values under the same Randomizable protocol without differentiating the method. The integer types that have `random(in:)` are all `FixedWidthInteger`.

This would be simply if disjunctions were allowed in generic where clauses:

```
where (Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint && Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger)
       || Bound: FixedWidthInteger
```

But, for thoughtful reasons, Swift only allows conjunctions.

Is there some way to make a where clause, possibly by introducing other protocol(s), that selects the intended types?

Other seeming dead-ends include adopted the protocol twice with non-overlapping where clauses (not allowed).

If nothing else comes to light, an obvious work around is to make separate protocols for floating point and integers, but that exactly replicates all the code which doesn't feel right to me.

See this question for more background on the overall goal: [Swift 4 -- Challenge trying to use Generics to reduce formulaic code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619650/swift-4-challenge-trying-to-use-generics-to-reduce-formulaic-code).

```
import SceneKit

public protocol Randomizable {
    associatedtype Value
    func random() -> Value
}

extension ClosedRange : Randomizable where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint,
                                           Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger {
    public typealias Value = Bound
    public func random() -> Value {
        return Value.random(in: self)
    }
}

extension Range : Randomizable where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint,
                                     Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger {
    public typealias Value = Bound
    public func random() -> Value {
        return Value.random(in: self)
    }
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    public static func random<R1: Randomizable, R2: Randomizable, R3: Randomizable>
      (_ xr: R1, _ yr: R2, _ zr: R3) -> SCNVector3
      where R1.Value == CGFloat, R2.Value == CGFloat, R3.Value == CGFloat {
        return SCNVector3(xr.random(), yr.random(), zr.random())
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that for ranges with integer bounds you can simply use randomElement()

Comment: Do you want to use this for other stuff than `SCNVector3`? Because `SCNVector3` uses `CGFloat` for its properties, and all other values should be automatically promoted to floats.

Comment: @Cristik: Yes, the idea was a general purpose tool for other composite structure initialization tasks. The current version works with all relevant floating point types, so that in itself is pretty useful. I don't have an immediate requirements for integers, but I'd rather not leave it half done unless there is not an elegant solution. In which case I will wait until I have an actual requirement for integers and figure it out then.